System.Device.Gpio issue when running on Up Board
My c# code to drive the gpio (SPI and Gpio pins) on the Up Board (x86 Intel Atom) compiled successfully in visual studio 2022. However when I try to run the code on my Up board under Windows 10, it flags up an error "cannot load file or assembly System.Device.Gpio, Version = 3.2.0.0". I installed the System.Device.Gpio using the Nuget package manager and also installed the bindings package. I have doubled checked that is IS version 3.2.0.0. I have also checked that  Copy Local  = True in the properties window in the References for System.Device.Gpio as advised in another post on this issue here, and the error message still flashes up. Anyone else have this issue and/or can someone please tell me how to fix the problem? As I said, the code compiles under VS2022. Thanks in anticipation! I've also tried to install nanoFramework.System.Device.Gpio but it won't install as the source mapping won't setup.
